# How to track the change happened in an object using `NGRX` Store in Angular 10 application

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am new to the `NGRX`. I need to compare a object and sent the data to the server. In my application I'm getting big collection of `object` from server to render on the screen and user will only edit few property of them. So rather than save sending the complete object to the server I prefer to send only changed property of the object. So, the payload is less and only those field in DB need to be updated.

1. Every edit happens there will be an update to store so at that time I need a mechanism to get the property changed and its object.

e.g: object which I'm getting while loading data:

```js
[
dummyObject:{
             prop0:string;
             prop1:string;
             prop2:string;
             prop3:string;
             prop4:string;
             prop5:string;
         },
dummyObject2:{
             obj2:string;
             obj3:string;
             obj4:string;
             obj5:string;
             obj6:string;
             obj7:string;
         }
]
```

User just will edit **prop3 & prop4**

Now I need to sent only object which property got changed with only changed property init.

```js
[
dummyObject:{
             prop3:string;
             prop4:string;
         }  
]
```

Is there any mechanism to get the changed using the `NGRX` Store functionality.

Any hint to dig deep.

Comment: So you could create a specific update action with a reducer that attached an additional property to your data (updated: true maybe?). Then you could create a selector that fetches only those objects that have that updated prop set to true? Does that make sense?

Comment: but i need to know which property got changed, also if a user type something and removed that wont consider as a changed property for example my old value is 'ABC' and added CD and removed CD, now the value back to ABC so this property shouldn't considered as changed.

Comment: @Aji Did you found any solution for it?

Comment: @Nidhinkumar couldn't find any direct approach i did a custom approach by writing a comparison service inside reducer and and keep a separate collection of changed property, while save i only sent those property collection to server